# Pure c alternative for typeof/typeid

Tags: c, typeof

Is there an alternative for the use of typeof or typeid using Microsoft Visual studio 2005 on windows? 
I know that typeof is a GCC Extension, but I'm interested on an alternative.

The following code fails: (Only when I using typeof or typeid)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define TEST_MACRO_TYPEOF(x, p)       \
{                                     \
  (x) = *(typeof(x) *)(p);            \
}                                     \

#define TEST_MACRO_TYPEID(x, p)       \
{                                     \
  (x) = *(typeid(x) *)(p);            \
}                                     \

#define TEST_MACRO_INT(x, p)          \
{                                     \
  (x) = *(int *)(p);                  \
}                                     \

#define TEST_MACRO_TYPE(x, p, type)   \
{                                     \
  (x) = *(type *)(p);                 \
}                                     \

int main()
{

  int *p;
  int a, b;
  a=0;
  b=20;
  p=&b;
  TEST_MACRO_INT(a, p)
  printf("b: %d\n",a);
  TEST_MACRO_TYPE(a, p, int)
  printf("b: %d\n",a);
  TEST_MACRO_TYPEID(a, p)
  printf("b: %d\n",a);
  TEST_MACRO_TYPEOF(a, p)
  printf("b: %d\n",a);
}
```

Errors:

```
source\main.c : warning C4013: 'typeid' undefined; assuming extern returning int
source\main.c : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
source\main.c : warning C4013: 'typeof' undefined; assuming extern returning int
source\main.c : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
```

Output (without using TEST_MACRO_TYPEID and TEST_MACRO_TYPEOF):

```
b: 20
b: 20
```

Comment: Rather than _Microsoft Visual studio 2005_  (it is 2016 after all), would a `_Generic` solution using a C11 compiler on widows work for you?

Comment: I need backward compatibility!

Comment: Could you specify which compiler(s) or versions of the C language spec you want to be compatible with?

Comment: I need to compile it with Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 V8.0. With the "Compile as C Code (/TC)" advanced option

Comment: Suggest posting example usages of `TEST_MACRO_TYPEOF()` and `TEST_MACRO_TYPEID()` to get a better idea of possible solutions.

Comment: The idea is the same of TEST_MACRO_TYPE, but with no need to pass type argument to the macro. Just cast of a pointer data. The example of use is in the main block.